# Async / Await, how do I force my function to wait until promise is resolved before it continues?

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, async-await

I would like my function to execute until the nextPageToken is null. When I execute the function the first time, it waits for the promise to be resolved. However as soon there is a nextPageToken present on the response, the function does not wait for the response and a stack overflow occurs.

It seems that f() is not suspended on the when await p.then() is called.

Am I totally misunderstanding how async/await works?

Any help would be greatly appreciated...

```
public apiResult2(path: string, objectName: string, params: any = { }) {
    let returnArray = [];
    const p = new Promise<any> ((resolve, reject) => {
      gapi.load('auth2:client', () => {
        gapi.client.request({
          path: path,
          params: params
        }).then(response => {
          // resolve this promise with the first key in the response object.
          resolve(response.result);
        }, reason => {
          console.log(reason);
          reject(reason.result);
        });
      });
    });
    let f = async () => {
      let nextPageToken = null;
      do {
        let r = await p.then(result => {
          if (result.hasOwnProperty(objectName)) {
            for (let obj of result[objectName]) {
              returnArray.push(obj);
            }
          }
          if (result.hasOwnProperty('nextPageToken')) {
            params.nextPageToken = result.nextPageToken;
            return result.nextPageToken;
            // nextPageToken = result.nextPageToken;
          } else {
            params.nextPageToken = null;
            return null;
            // nextPageToken = null;
          }
        });
        nextPageToken = r;
        console.log(r);
      } while (nextPageToken);
    };
    f();
    return returnArray;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your function needs to "await" some async call, then it must also be async. Your function `apiResult2` is not going to wait for `f` to be finished, in order to `return returnArray`.

**EDIT:**

The main issue here is that you are trying to reuse the promise `p` to make different requests, but this is not possible. The promise `p` will be initialized with the parameters for the first request, and all the calls to `p.then` will be fulfilled with the same result: the response for the first page request.

I made some small changes to your code, and got it working with a mocked interface:

```
const apiResult2 = async (path: string, objectName: string, params: any = { }) => {
    const requestPage = async () => new Promise<any> ((resolve, reject) => {
        gapi.load('auth2:client', () => {
            gapi.client.request({
                path: path,
                params: params
            }).then(response => {
                // resolve this promise with the first key in the response object.
                resolve(response.result);
            }, reason => {
                console.log(reason);
                reject(reason.result);
            });
        });
    });

    let returnArray: string[] = [];
    do {
        const page = await requestPage();

        if (page.hasOwnProperty(objectName)) {
            for (let obj of page[objectName]) {
                returnArray.push(obj);
            }
        }

        if (page.hasOwnProperty('nextPageToken')) {
            params.nextPageToken = page.nextPageToken;
        } else {
            params.nextPageToken = null;
        }
    } while (params.nextPageToken);

    return returnArray;
}
```

Usage example:

```
apiResult2(path, objectName, params).then(
    result => console.log(result),
    err => console.log('error', err)
);
```

Comment: I tried making `apiResult2()` an async function, moving the returnArray inside `f()` and returning it, then adding `return await f();` However, the result is still the same.

Here is where  I call apiResult2 from, if that helps?
`ngOnInit() {
    this.sub = this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.students = this.googleApi.apiResult2('https://classroom.googleapis.com/v1/courses/' + params['id'] + '/students', 'students');
    });
  }`

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! The function now waits for the first Api call to finish before requesting the next one.

Two unexpected things are happening when I use the new function.

1. Every time the function is fun, 2 of the same api calls are dispatched together.
2. When I console.log the return value, the result is a promise and not an Array?: `(ZoneAwarePromise {__zone_symbol__state: null, __zone_symbol__value: Array(0)}__zone_symbol__state: true__zone_symbol__value: Array(43)__proto__: Object
)` In the previous function the return was an Array... Any ideas?

Comment: Ahhh, disregard the comment above. Looking at the usage example, I can see that I need to resolve the promise in the calling function!

Works as expected!! Thank you!!!